# How to add an application to the desktop context menu for a specific folder?

Tags: c#, registry, contextmenu

I'm trying to put my own menu in the Windows Desktop ContextMenu. Something similar to what Dropbox makes. When in the dropbox folder, a menu called Dropbox is displayed and lets you perform tasks on a given file.

I know that for all folders I need to use this registry key:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell
```

Anyone know how to place my own menu **in a specific folder**?

Regards!